# Getting plain text of a field in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

I have a content type including two fields: First name(node title) and Last name(text field)
In node.tpl I want to print first name and last name sequentially.

I use the following code to do this but it prints first name and last name in seperate lines.That's because last name is wrapped in a div.Is there any way to get raw text of the last name field?

```
<?php print $node->title . render($content['field_last_name']);?>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this out:

```
<?php
print $content['field_phone_number'][0]['#markup'];
?>
```

Simply replace the 'field_phone_number' with 'field_last_name'.  You can do the same for the first name too.

Comment: I can confirm that this works, and it's _much_ better than what I was doing! But I can't help but wonder if there's a more robust, "offical" way to do this. Is this "the way"?